# Powershell regex.match() metacharacters

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

```
$reg = [regex]"\bobject-group\b network Gateways[\s\S]*?(?=\nobject-group\b)"
```

This is my content to select

```
object-group network something
 network-object host blahblah
 network-object host blahblah
 network-object host blahblah
 network-object host blahblah
object-group network Gateways
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
object-group network baller
 network-object host blahblah
 network-object host blahblah
 network-object host blahblah
```

My expression works fine on Regex Tester, but migrating over the Powershell I just can't figure out what meta characters are wrong, but I get no results. Any help would be amazing? : )

The data is taken from a file. and stored in a file. The wanted outcome is....

```
object-group network Gateways
     network-object blahblahbalh
     network-object blahblahbalh
     network-object blahblahbalh
     network-object blahblahbalh
     network-object blahblahbalh
     network-object blahblahbalh
     network-object blahblahbalh
     network-object blahblahbalh
     network-object blahblahbalh
     network-object blahblahbalh
     network-object blahblahbalh
     network-object blahblahbalh
     network-object blahblahbalh
     network-object blahblahbalh
     network-object blahblahbalh
     network-object blahblahbalh
```

Comment: This would be much easier to decipher if you said what sections of your content you're trying to match. Is the content in a variable or a file?

Comment: You are very right.... Updated - Its stored in a variable, and the match is added to the bottom of the post.

Comment: This works for me if I have the data in a here-string. How is your variable populated? Is it a string array maybe? Again, this works again a single string. If you are using `Get-Content` consider using the `-Raw` switch

Answer (score 0):

Works for me using the code that you posted. I'm in PowerShell 4.0, here's what I did:

```
$reg = [regex]"\bobject-group\b network Gateways[\s\S]*?(?=\nobject-group\b)"
$str = @"
object-group network something
 network-object host blahblah
 network-object host blahblah
 network-object host blahblah
 network-object host blahblah
object-group network Gateways
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
object-group network baller
 network-object host blahblah
 network-object host blahblah
 network-object host blahblah
"@

> $($reg.Match($str)).Value
object-group network Gateways
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
 network-object blahblahbalh
```